# Best Database to be shipped with my application?

Tags: windows, installation, database-recommendation

I have a .NET core application using a database. I need to create an installer using NSIS where I will be packaging my application along with a database, so that the client can easily install my application and database along with all its dependencies using a simple wizard.

> I want a suggestion regarding the database.

Requirements:

1. Easy to install; it must be light weight; as small a dependency count as possible; have zip binaries to install; and error free during
   installation.
2. Database should be able to handle a large number of records and remote connections.

What I have tried:

- MSSQL Server: no binary file option; has large size and has so many dependencies.
- SQLite: it's file-based; no remote connections possible
- PostgreSQL: it was a perfect choice; but it has many installation issues and bugs – even the official installer failed to install on some of the machines.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using .NET Core, your best bet is to stick within the same stack if possible. While I understand the nicety of having a *one-click* installer for your end users, it's certainly not unusual to provide installation instructions with setting up the database server in addition to the application installer.

That aside, what do you consider a "*large number of records*"? You can definitely bundle SQL Server Express in your application so that it is automatically installed with your application. [Here's an example article](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/940.how-to-embed-sql-server-express-in-an-application.aspx) on how to do so. While there's no limitation on number of records, there is a limitation on each database being no bigger than 10 GB, since this is the free version of SQL Server. (Of course you can have as many databases as you like though. :) I'm sure there's a way to incorporate a non-Express version of SQL Server too, if the paid version was needed.